# Como abrir um JFrame passado como parâmetro?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Minha ideia é abrir essa janela passada como parâmetro sem que ela perca nenhum atributo, por exemplo, tenho a classe :

```
public class Teste {

    JFrame janela = new JFrame;    

    public ControllerJPreTransacao(JFrame janela) {

            this.janela = janela;
            initEvents();
    }

    private void initEvents(){

            janela.setVisible(true); //NullPointerException
    }

}
```

Como puderam notar o comentário, em determinada parte da classe o eclipse acusa `NullPointerException` na linha que deixo a `janela` visível, o que não faz sentido, uma vez que eu já instanciei a mesma no começo da classe. Devido a esse erro o eclipse não chega nem a abrir o frame. No que estou errando?

Comment: Olha bem o que você está fazendo. Se recebe um Frame como parametro, pra que new Frame? Remova isso `JFrame janela = new JFrame;`, já que você está recebendo uma janela no construtor.

Comment: Já tentei fazer sem esse `new`, porém a IDE continua acusando o mesmo  erro, na mesma linha ...

Comment: Como você está iniciando esta classe? O JFrame está sendo passado como nulo.

Comment: Boa ! Era exatamente isso que estava faltando ! Não havia instanciado a janela passada como parâmetro !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro ocorre porque provavelmente não está sendo passado nenhum parâmetro para o construtor, além da instanciação está incorreta, o jeito correto é:

```
JFrame janela = new JFrame();
```

Como você quer exibir a janela recebida no construtor, remova a instanciação do atributo,  deixe apenas `JFrame janela;`, e trate no método se está nulo ou não.

Na chamada desta classe, lembre-se de passar um `JFrame` válido como parâmetro assim `Teste t = new Teste(algumFrame);` senão vai continuar ocorrendo o erro.